# Are there terminals that support true color?

Tags: colors, terminal

I cannot understand why Apple's default terminal has only 16 colors, iterm2 etc support 256 colors, but X11's terminal supports true color (although its user interface is crappy).

My question is in two parts:

1. **Why, in this day and age, are terminals not able to support higher colors (i.e., higher than 16 and 256)?**

   The last time I asked this, I only got rude comments like *"Why don't you write one yourself"*... I'm asking seriously, because I do not know about what goes into the internals of a terminal and why the constraint. Is it simply because there is no demand?
2. **If I'm wrong and there are good terminals that support true color, could you recommend them?**

   My observations are based on a Mac, but other platform answers are welcome too, because they might be helpful to others.

Comment: What would all these colors be used for?

Comment: @delnan: For one I can make use of themes for vim & emacs that are designed for the GUI version (i.e., true colors)

Comment: @user564376 btw, it's possible now to use GUI color schemes for terminal vim http://usevim.com/2013/05/31/24bit/

Comment: @delnan This is not about color, this is about eliminating palette-based color indexing, which basically is a hurdle for anyone who ever tried to install a color scheme for their vim preferences. Truecolor color setting lets one simply and effectively define and address actual color, as opposed to color swatch reference, which complicates things, as applications do not know what colors they are really outputting. Again, this is not only about color, this is about ways to specify color.

Comment: Is Mac OS terminal still not supporting truecolor in 2020?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the older days where terminals originate, they were hardware, and their colourfulness was limited by hardware constraints (i.e. memory shortage). Now we mostly use virtual terminals, which often emulate these older devices in software. So, one point is whether the software terminal actually *emulates a device with its historical limitations.*

Another point is that there are no *conceptual* limitations on colours, fonts or anything. This is because terminal is controlled by commands, which are simply special reserved sequences of characters. Commands are not standardized and differ from a terminal to a terminal. And that's exactly why there are virtually no such exotic functions implemented, as *it would leave the users with two limiting options:*

- require all terminals to support the feature (which is not practically feasible)
- limit the usage of the software to few particular terminals which do support the feature (which is highly unpleasant).

The third point I'd notice is that such features are *not really needed* by majority of people.

Comment: Related to the third point, it is probably pretty rare for an application to need more than 16 colors but not *also* need something other than a monospaced 80x24 grid of characters.  While it can sometimes be advantageous for an application to be usable by anyone with a terminal emulator program that understands VT100 or ANSI sequences, applications that would require something beyond the capabilities offered by such terminals would generally be best served by something which is nothing like a terminal.

Comment: @supercat i.e. a graphical display, I strongly agree.

Comment: It's only not needed because nobody knows too much of it or uses/supports it. If it was actually supported by developers, say for stuff like vim, etc, it may just breathe some new life into the darn terminal.

Answer (score 31):

[KDE Konsole has true colour support](https://github.com/robertknight/konsole/blob/master/user-doc/README.moreColors), i.e. every character can have a different 24-bit colour.

Xterm and most other terminal emulators these days have a palette of 256 colours, whereby each of those colours can be chosen out of the full 24-bit range.

Comment: Adding to that, there is a defined escape code for "nearest color in the palette to this r/g/b tuple". xterm picks the nearest color out of its 256 in that case, and apparently Konsole simply uses it as-is.

Comment: FYI: I think the escapes are fg: "\e[38;2;<R>;<G>;<B>m" and bg: "\e[48;2;<R>;<G>;<B>m"

Comment: This was added to libvte [recently](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vte/commit/?h=vte-0-36&id=c5a32b491afe783b02eec49b1f02241163ba4367).

Comment: and... \e[38;5;<0-255>m or \e[38;5;<0-255>m for the 256-color palette, its sad that programs that take advantage of 256-color palette features do not also support the 24-bit/true color feature as well. Many people simply just do not know about them, because they are not well documented until just recently. In fact, until a year ago, even I was not aware of terminals other than fbterm (with its severely incompatible) support for true colors, i think the sequence wasn't even valid sgr, something like \e[1 or 2;(r;g;b or 256-color index)} or something like that, dont quote me on that!

Answer (score 31):

I know I'm very late for the party, but I found this :
[a gist titled "True Color (16 million colors) support in various terminal applications and terminals"](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728), which gives information about which terminals support true colour and related discussions in the corresponding communities.

Comment: Now in https://github.com/termstandard/colors

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a quick link for Mac OS X, I just got iTerm2 nightly build and it works perfectly with true color:
https://iterm2.com/downloads/nightly/#/section/home

To answer the question about why this is useful: I do research on color, and being able to display colors right in the terminal is super useful for debugging/scripting/you name it.