# Why do we have max. 256 colors in terminal emulators?

Tags: shell, colors, terminal, xterm

I was just fiddling around with a 256 color VIM theme and noticed that 256 colors are just not enough sometimes. I would love a terminal that supports at least the HTML color range from `#000000` to `#FFFFFF` (65536 colors).

So i asked myself...

- Is there a good reason why there is no terminal emulator with more than 256 colors?
- Or am i missing out on one and somebody already built one?

Comment: There are plenty of terminal emulators with more than 256 colors. Very often vim just requires that the right environment is set. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim

Comment: I have 256 colors working in my environent, i was just wondering if one could have more... Thanks though!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there terminals that support true color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403744/are-there-terminals-that-support-true-color)

Answer (score 3):

It's because that's how many colors you could encode in a single byte.  Not only that, actually most terminals only had 16 colors (using only 4 of the 8 bits) the other 4 bits were flags used to indicate some thing to do with a character. Most common flags were: highlight, underline, blinking and reverse;  (or some other terminal capability)